# Getting the diff of a package update

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, diff, source

Before (or after) updating a package with `apt-get update`, how can I view the source code diff between the the new and the old version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the *source code* from the Debian repositories using:

`apt-get source <PACKAGE>`

It will download 3 files, a `.dsc` that describes the package, a `.orig.tar.gz` that contains the source code, and a `.diff.gz` that contains the changes.

This will work if in `/etc/apt/sources.list/` you have included `deb-src` entries, for example:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
```

Will let me download `deb` packages as long as source code from *Debian Wheezy* repositories.

Comment: For the package I'm interested in, libtasn1-6, the file containing the diffs has the suffix `.debian.tar.xz`.

Comment: That file contains the diffs between the upstream source code and the Debian package, not the diffs between the previous version and the new version.

Comment: @StephenKitt I received an email from apticron which sais that `libtasn1-6` needs to be updated and that the update adds the `20_CVE-2015-3622.diff` patch. After `apt-get source libtasn1-6` I can find this patch in `debian/patches` in the downloaded source directory. Therefor I don't understand your claim that the source package doesn't contain the diff between the previous and the new version.

Comment: *In this particular instance*, because you're upgrading from `libtasn1-6` 4.2-3 to 4.2-3+deb8u1, and the only change is the addition of the CVE fix, then yes, the source package contains the diff. But *in general*, that's not the case: to see all the changes from one version to another (which is how I understood your question), you need to download both versions and compare them.

Answer (score 3):

The more general approach is to compare the two source packages corresponding to the version you're upgrading from and the version you're upgrading to. To find the former you may need to look through the [snapshots](http://snapshot.debian.org/); the latter should be available from your archive. Then run `debdiff` on the two `.dsc` files.

Here's an example, comparing [stella](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/stella) 4.1.1-1 (the previous version in `unstable`) and 4.6.1-2 (the current version in `unstable`):

```
dget http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20140916T041024Z/pool/main/s/stella/stella_4.1.1-1.dsc
dget http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/s/stella/stella_4.6.1-2.dsc
debdiff stella_4.1.1-1.dsc stella_4.6.1-2.dsc
```

In general you can replace the second line with

```
apt-get --download-only source stella
```

In some cases more specific tools can be used; `stella`'s packaging is maintained in `git`, so you can run

```
debcheckout stella
cd stella
git diff debian/4.1.1-1 debian/4.6.1-2
```

to compare the tags directly.

`dget`, `debdiff` and `debcheckout` are in the `devscripts` package.

Comment: One could also simply use upstream's source code repository.

Comment: Yes, although that won't show changes in packaging (which may include patches to the upstream code).